# Server fetched partials + pagination

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I try to make live search with laravel 10 and Javascript.
I have issue with pagination, get data with ajax first time and when I try goes next page it return blade without styling.
I have this case

```
Route::get('room/parcels/{status}/search', [ParcelController::class, 'search'])->name('parcel.search');
```

this is in my route:

```
Route::prefix('room')->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('parcels')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/{status}', [ParcelController::class, 'getParcel'])->name('getParcel');
        Route::get('{status}/filter', [ParcelController::class, 'filter'])->name('parcel.filter');
        Route::get('/filter/{is_declared}', [ParcelController::class, 'undeclaredFilter'])->name('parcel.undeclared.filter');
    });
});
```

in controller:

```
public function getParcel($status)
    {
        if (!$status) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $parcels = Parcel::where('status', $status)->paginate(5);

        return view('user.parcels.index', compact('parcels'));
    }

    public function search(Request $request, $status)
    {   
        if (!$status) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('user.parcels._list', compact('parcels'))->render();
    }
```

I have index.blade.php for main blade and _list.blade.php where I have list of parcels

in index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('style')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/parcels_list.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('content')
    @if(session('message'))
        <x-alert />
    @endif
    <section class="max-w-[800px] pt-10 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold font-arialCaps border-l-4 border-primary pl-2">ამანათები</h1>
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-10 mt-10">
            <div class="shadow w-full rounded">
                <div class="flex gap-2 border-b">
                    <a href="{{ route('getParcel', 'received') }}" class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-4 w-full text-sm text-primary-black py-2 {{ request()->segment(3) == 'received' ? 'bg-white border-b-2 border-primary' :  ''}}">icon here

                        <span class="{{ request()->segment(3) == 'received' ? 'text-primary font-bold' :  ''}} text-xs md:text-sm">მიღებული</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ route('getParcel', 'sent') }}" class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-4 w-full text-sm text-primary-black py-2 {{ request()->segment(3) == 'sent' ? 'bg-white border-b-2 border-primary' :  ''}}">icon here

                        <span class="{{ request()->segment(3) == 'sent' ? 'text-primary font-bold' :  ''}} text-xs md:text-sm">გამოგზავნილი</span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{ route('getParcel', 'arrived') }}" class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-4 w-full text-sm text-primary-black py-2 {{ request()->segment(3) == 'arrived' ? 'bg-white border-b-2 border-primary' :  ''}}">icon here

                        <span class="{{ request()->segment(3) == 'arrived' ? 'text-primary font-bold' :  ''}} text-xs md:text-sm">ჩამოსული</span>
                    </a>
                
                    <a href="{{ route('getParcel', 'takeout') }}" class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center gap-4 w-full text-sm text-primary-black py-2 {{ request()->segment(3) == 'takeout' ? 'bg-white border-b-2 border-primary' :  ''}}">icon here
                        <span class="{{ request()->segment(3) == 'takeout' ? 'text-primary font-bold' :  ''}} text-xs md:text-sm">გატანილი</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="parcels-list-container">
                        <div class="parcels-list-header">
                            <div class="parcels-list-header_left">
                                <input id="parcel_all" type="checkbox" class="hidden peer"  />
                                <label for="parcel_all"
                                class="relative flex items-center justify-center p-0.5 peer-checked:before:hidden before:block before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full before:bg-white w-4 h-4 cursor-pointer bg-primary border rounded overflow-hidden fill-current">checkbox here
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <a href="" class="flex gap-2 bg-primary p-2.5 rounded text-sm text-center text-white hover:bg-primary/90">გადახდა <span id="totalPrice"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul id="parcels-wrapper" class="pb-3">
                            <p class="text-center">ამანათები ვერ მოიძებნა</p>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pagination">
            {{-- {{ $parcels->appends(request()->query())->links('vendor.pagination.custom')->withPath('/search') }} --}}
            {{ $parcels->appends(request()->query())->withPath('/room/parcels/received/search')->links('vendor.pagination.custom') }}
        </div>
    </section>


    <script>
        function getParcels() {
            fetch('/room/parcels/received/search')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(html => {
                    document.querySelector('#parcels-wrapper').innerHTML = html
                })
        }

        getParcels()

    </script>
@endsection
```

in this file I have ajax

this is _list.blade.php

```
@foreach ($parcels as $parcel)
    <li class="parcels_list {{ !$parcel->is_paid ? 'bg-red-300/30' : '' }}">
        <div class="place-self-center">
            @if (!$parcel->is_paid)
                <input id="parcel_{{ $parcel->id }}" type="checkbox" class="check_pay hidden peer" data-price="{{ $parcel->price }}" />
                <label for="parcel_{{ $parcel->id }}"
            class="relative flex items-center justify-center p-0.5 peer-checked:before:hidden before:block before:absolute before:w-full before:h-full before:bg-white w-4 h-4 cursor-pointer bg-primary border rounded overflow-hidden fill-current">iconHere
                </label>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <span class="pb-2"><span class="fi fi-tr text-base pr-4"></span> {{ $parcel->tracking_code }}</span>
            <div class="gap-8 grid grid-cols-[60px_80px_1fr] items-end text-gray-500 text-sm">
                <span>{{ $parcel->physical_weight }}kg</span>
                <span class="flex text-xs">{{ $parcel->declaration->price ?? '' }} {{ $parcel->declaration->currency ?? '' }}</span>
                <span class="max-w-[100px] overflow-hidden overflow-ellipsis whitespace-nowrap">{{ $parcel->declaration->category->name['ka'] ?? '' }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-2 md:order-none">
            <div class="pb-2">
                @if ($parcel->is_paid)
                    <span class="bg-green-300/70 text-green-800 px-2 py-1 rounded text-xs sm:text-sm">{{ abs($parcel->price) }} ₾</span>    
                @else
                    <span class="text-xs sm:text-sm">{{ abs($parcel->price) }} ₾</span>
                    <span class="text-xs pl-4">გადაუხდელი</span>

                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-[60px_80px] gap-6 text-xs text-gray-500">
                <div class="flex gap-1">iconHere 11 Feb
                </div class="flex gap-1">
                <div class="flex gap-1">iconHere16 Feb
                </div class="flex gap-1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="flex gap-1 justify-center mb-4">
                <a href="" class="block p-1.5 rounded bg-gray-200/80 hover:bg-gray-200/50">iconHere
                </a>
                <a href="" class="block p-1.5 rounded bg-gray-200/80 hover:bg-gray-200/50">iconHere
                </a>
                <a href="" class="block p-1.5 rounded bg-gray-200/80 hover:bg-gray-200/50">iconHere
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-1">
                {{-- <a href="" class="bg-primary p-2.5 rounded text-white text-sm text-center block">გადახდა</a> --}}
                @if ($parcel->declaration)
                    <a href="{{ route('parcel.declaration.edit', $parcel->tracking_code) }}" class="bg-primary p-2.5 rounded text-xs md:text-sm text-center text-white hover:bg-primary/90">დეკლარაცია</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('parcel.declaration.create', $parcel->tracking_code) }}" class="bg-primary-orange p-2.5 rounded text-xs md:text-sm text-center text-white hover:bg-primary-orange/90">დეკლარაცია</a>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

when index page loaded first time it displayed 5 items but when I try click pagination it change url as I have from this `/room/parcels/received` to `/room/parcels/received/search?page=2` but now it shows `_list.blade` page only

first time when I don't have `->withPath('/room/parcels/received/search')` and when I clicked pagination it changed pages but don't changed view it shows same items which loaded first time.
I looked for a solution where it was written that you should use it `->withPath('/room/parcels/received/search')`, but now it change url and return another blade.
Also I try change my controller from this

```
public function getParcel($status)
    {
        if (!$status) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $parcels = Parcel::where('status', $status)->paginate(5);

        return view('user.parcels.index', compact('parcels'));
    }

    public function search(Request $request, $status)
    {   
        if (!$status) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('user.parcels._list', compact('parcels'))->render();
    }
```

to this

```
public function getParcel()
    {
        return view('user.parcels.index');
    }

    public function search(Request $request, $status)
    {   
        if (!$status) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('user.parcels._list', compact('parcels'))->render();
    }
```

And I moved the pagination link to _list.blade.php but it doesn't work,

can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: if you are making an ajax search, the pagination needs to be via ajax too